# Getting Null Pointer exception when trying to get value from hashmap object in java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have one field in my DTO named Details class something like this

```
class Datas{
    private Details details;
}
```

In Details class I have field something like this

```
class Details{
private HashMap<String, Data> data;
}
```

in Data class I have variables like

```
private String name;
private String id;
```

Now when I am trying to get and set the value something like this

```
 information.setDescription(
                        item.get(i).getDatas().Details().get("data").getName());
```

I am getting null pointer exception ,

sample Json Object

```
 "data" : {
               "12345" : {
               "name" : "bhushan",
                "id" : "1"
    }
```

error:-
java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: should be `.get("12345")`

Comment: Does `Details()` get the HashMap inside the `Details` object or the `Details` object itself?

Answer (score 1):

```
information.setDescription(
                    item.get(i).getDatas().Details().get("data").getName());
```

Case sensitive matters!

Comment: that is a typos mistake , I have changed , but still getting same